# Android Studio debugger gets stuck (hedgehog)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, debugging, testing

Since my upgrade to "Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1" the debugger is not working properly anymore when working with an emulator.

Even when im trying to inspect simple assignments or view current variable values, the debugger gets stuck on "Collecting data...".
Going to the next breakpoint or skipping it entirely results in "Waiting until last debugger command completes".

So far i've tried the common cleans and rebuilds that fix many other problems.
I dont use methodbreakpoints, my machine is potent enough, my classes and methods are small and rely on no external information (e.g. server, db-calls...).

Working with these settings takes no real effect:
[image: AS Debugger Settings]

Also editing the debug configuration to Java/ Native/ Dual takes no effect:
[image: Runconfiguration]

Has enyone encountered the same issue and was able to fix it?